# Balance it out (double factorial problem)

Tags: combinatorics

Amit was given a balance and n weights (where n is a positive integer) of weight 2^0, 2^1, 2^2,.... 2^(n-1). He is now assigned a task to place the weight that has not been placed on the balance, either on the right pan or the left pan until all of the weights have been placed.But at every step he needs to make sure that the right pan is never heavier than left pan. You have to help him determine the number of ways in which this can be done.

example:
if n=2 so weight will be-1,2
answer is -3

if n=3 so weight will be of 1,2,4
and answer is -15

This problem was in last contest of codechef that is over now, solutions are also available there but i am not getting the algorithm or solution .I dont know but the solution series it similar to double factorial ,i am not familiar with that.Please explain.

Comment: If you want an explanation of a specific solution/algorithm, you should include a reference to it.

Comment: Do we assume that he has to place the weights in that order? Or can we change up the order? Judging from your claim of answer is 3, it seems like we have control over the order. Is this true?

Comment: how , please suggest me sir , new here.

Comment: If you start the url, others can help you edit it in.

Comment: any order but at any time the weight on the right pan should never be higher that left one.we need to answer total number of ways like if n=2, and answer is three solve it you can understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Proceed by induction.

Show that if there are $P_k$ ways to arrange the weights $2^0, 2^1, \ldots 2^k$, then there are $(2k+1)$ ways to arrange the weights $2^0, 2^1, \ldots 2^{k+1}$.

Proof: If there are $P_k$ ways to arrange the weights $2^0, 2^1, \ldots 2^k$ according to the conditions, then there are $P_k$ ways to arrange the weights $2^1, 2^2, \ldots 2^{k+1}$.

> Now consider where we place the weight $2^0$. It can be placed in the Left pan at any point in time, giving $k+1$ possibilities.
>  When can it be placed in the Right pan? It can't be placed in the Right pan right at the start (since then the right pan will be heavier than the left). However, after the first move, the weight in the Left pan is at least 2 more than the weight in the right pan (Why?). Hence, we can place $2^0$ in the right pan at any other time, giving $k$ possibilities.

Hence $P_{k+1} = (2k+1) P_k$.

Observe that $P_1 = 1$, which proves that $P_n = (2n-1) \times (2n-3) \times (2n-5) \times \ldots \times 1$.

Comment: i am not getting please elaborate it if possible.

Comment: thanx sir i got.. you explained nicely .... but you know :)